# Android Rest APi using node js connection refused error

Tags: android, node.js, server

> this is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rest_test');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api',require('./routes/api'))
app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("express has started on port 3000");
});
```

> this is running perfectly on the browser but when I try to request REST
>   API I get Connection refused error. I have gone through all given solutions on StackOverflow but nothing worked for me.

Comment: > _when I try to request REST API I get Connection refused error_
Where are you making this request from? The same machine as the server , or your phone?

Comment: same machine on which server is made

Comment: For the case where it fails, how are you making this REST API call? i.e what is the client that you are using. Also, what is the full url that you are hitting, as it appears on the cloud?